# how to scrape age group of users from tripadvisor python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am struggling to extract information of users from TripAdvisor.

If you look at the review, click on the username or photo, it will appear with more information which is ageg_group, contributes, helpful vote, and cities visited.

I want to scrape the age group and cities visited. Please look at the image below for more detail.

[image]

I am able to click on it, but it only shows the information of the first user and it doesnot move to the second one. I put it into the for_loop, but it didn't work.

```
info = browser.find_element_by_class_name('info_text')
info.click()
```

Anyone has any advice to scrape all the user's information using python, please?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: try with loop, to click on each user and get the details.

Answer (score 0):

As @Murthi suggested try looping through it should look something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 


data = []
my_xpath = '//div[@class="info_text"]'
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, my_xpath)))
users_info = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(my_xpath)
for index, user in enumerate(users_info):
    user.click()
    inf = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="countsReviewEnhancementsItem"]')
    data.append(inf)

    try:
        users_info[index+1].click()
    except :
        pass
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try, but then I got this error: Element <div class="info_text"> is not clickable at point (111.66666412353516,584.3499755859375) because another element <div class="ui_backdrop"> obscures it

Comment: I noticed that, if I want to click the second user, then I have to left click 2 times in order to open the information. I think that is why it is not working...

Comment: Please direct me how to let it click 2 times from the second user to get the data, and one for the first user. Thank you.

Comment: Please use this site: https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/Hotel_Review-g56003-d266157-Reviews-Magnolia_Hotel_Houston-Houston_Texas.html

Comment: I didn't do all the work for you... but hope I helped I gotta go to work...

Comment: added that xpath as a bonus ;-)

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, you can except it.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your updated. I found another way is that click the "X" button. But it didn't move to the second user's information. It only opens the first user's infor...

Comment: Applying your codes, I got this error: TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Comment: the code was just to show the structure... I don't have time to check I got to work